# Tips for checking data integrity / data sanity?

Tags: data, data-cleaning, beginner

I've read a few vague articles and watched a couple of YouTube videos on data integrity and data sanity, but none of them have mentioned ways to **actually check these on datasets.**

I am interested in knowing **the steps** to check such factors on datasets.

Kindly let me know if this is too broad, I can think of more specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things to check in a data set, there could be a lot more but i'm sharing what i did myself.

- ***Check the NULLs in your columns, count them to see if there is a column that contains too many NULLs and that you might want to eliminate***
- ***Plot your data distribution each column at a time to see the range of values taken by your data, to see if there is something particularly remarquable about its behavior.***
- And I'd recommend this famous [kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/headsortails/pytanic) on Kaggle where a good exploratory data analysis is done.

Answer (score 1):

You could check your dataset for:

- Null values/Missing values
- Zero values
- Negative values
- Max & Min values for each column
- Checks for Date values if there are any in your dataset, if these values make sense.